# Multiple background scripts in a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've been tasked with creating a Google Chrome extension. So far, everything works fine. However, I would like to be able to use multiple background scripts (what I mean is
`"background" : {"scripts" : ["background.js"]},` if what I'm talking about is unclear) rather than creating multiple extensions. Is this possible?

Regards,

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Since `background.scripts` is an array, I would expect this to work.   What have you tried?

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet. Just wanted to know if it can be done. How can I test if `background:{"scripts": ["background.js","bg.js"]},` works? Also, I've got a scructure in mind like `if the keyword is foo, do this; if the keyword is bar, do that`. Is this possible?

Comment: It seems it would be easier to try it than to ask a question about it on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages#manifest):

> A background page will be generated by the extension system that includes each of the files listed in the scripts property.

So yes, it should work. Simply declare multiple scripts:

```
...
"background": {
  "scripts": [
    "background.js",
    "backgroundone.js",
    "backgroundtwo.js"
  ]
},
...
```

All of these scripts would work as if loaded into the same page; they will all share the same context.

Comment: Keep in mind that the scripts will be executed in the same context as if they were all loaded in one page.

Comment: You should note that the order in the "scripts" array can matter, as they get executed in order. Therefore if "background.js" immediately depends on something that "backgroundtwo.js" puts on the window, it will break with the ordering in the example.

Comment: Lets say I want two different background scripts for two different things. Will both of these background scripts interact with each other or slow each other down? Both of my background scripts have a lot to do with efficiency and speed and I want each to do there own script without slowing down each other. @abraham

Comment: Is there any way to use multiple scripts in manifest version 3 ?

Answer (score 13):

In manifest version3:

```
---------manifest.json

"background": {
    "service_worker": "bg-wrapper.js"
}

---------bg-wrapper.js
try {
  importScripts('background.js');
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```